# 28 Yaksha Generals

Tags: buddhist-cosmology, literature, mythology

I've noticed reference to the 28 Yaksha Generals in several texts. To my current knowledge, the Mahāmāyūrīvidyārājñī Sūtra and the 卍新纂續藏經 Vol. 02, No. 183 (二十八夜叉大軍王名號) are the only text that explicitly lists them.

Are there any other extant material that lists the names of these generals? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there are[12 Yaksha Generals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Heavenly_Generals) and 28 Legions Serving Avalokiteshvara, but they refer to different beings.

In Japanese Buddhism, the latter are called 二十八部衆, [Nijūhachi Bushū](http://www.onmarkproductions.com/html/28-bushu-kannon.shtml). The link contains a list of all 28 names in Japanese.

Comment: Those are both different sets of deities than what I'm referring to. To my knowledge, they are known as the 二十八夜叉大軍王 in Chinese.